# MVVMCross ValueConverter Bool To MvxColor/Color

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, converters, mvvmcross

i was trying to implement the ValueConverter for MVVMCross, but aparently it is not working as i would expect. So at the moment i just got another Property which does the conversion (MvxColor to TextColor) for me and bind it to my Layout.
But ofc i would rather use the value converters, so maybe you have an idea what iam doing wrong:

The binding error iam currently getting:

```
    06-09 16:29:29.820 I/MvxBind (16312):  61,64 Problem seen during binding execution for binding TextColor for Changed - problem InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
06-09 16:29:29.820 I/MvxBind (16312):     at MvvmCross.Plugins.Color.Droid.BindingTargets.MvxTextViewTextColorBinding.SetValueImpl (System.Object target, System.Object value) [0x0000a] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-09 16:29:29.820 I/MvxBind (16312):   at MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxConvertingTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00088] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-09 16:29:29.820 I/MvxBind (16312):   at MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (System.Object value) [0x00024] in <filename unknown>:0 
MvxBind:Error: 61,64 Problem seen during binding execution for binding TextColor for Changed - problem InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
06-09 16:29:29.820 I/mono-stdout(16312): MvxBind:Error: 61,64 Problem seen during binding execution for binding TextColor for Changed - problem InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
06-09 16:29:29.820 I/mono-stdout(16312):      at MvvmCross.Plugins.Color.Droid.BindingTargets.MvxTextViewTextColorBinding.SetValueImpl (System.Object target, System.Object value) [0x0000a] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at MvvmCross.Plugins.Color.Droid.BindingTargets.MvxTextViewTextColorBinding.SetValueImpl (System.Object target, System.Object value) [0x0000a] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxConvertingTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00088] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-09 16:29:29.830 I/mono-stdout(16312):   at MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxConvertingTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00088] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (System.Object value) [0x00024] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-09 16:29:29.830 I/mono-stdout(16312):   at MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (System.Object value) [0x00024] in <filename unknown>:0 
[0:] MvxBind:Error: 61,64 Problem seen during binding execution for binding TextColor for Changed - problem InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
      at MvvmCross.Plugins.Color.Droid.BindingTargets.MvxTextViewTextColorBinding.SetValueImpl (System.Object target, System.Object value) [0x0000a] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxConvertingTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00088] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (System.Object value) [0x00024] in <filename unknown>:0
```

My Layout-Snippet:

```
<EditText
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
      android:textColor="@color/schaefflerlightgreen"
      local:MvxBind="TextColor Changed,Converter=MvxBoolToColorValueConverter" />
```

The two converter classes i tried out:

```
    public class MvxBoolToMvxColorValueConverter: MvxColorValueConverter<bool>
{

    protected override MvxColor Convert(bool value, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value)
        {
            // FF0000
            return new MvxColor(255, 0, 0);
        }
        //227D41
        return new MvxColor(34, 125, 65);
    }
}

    public class MvxBoolToColorValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, Color>
{

    protected override Color Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value)
        {
            // FF0000
            return new Color(255, 0, 0);
        }
        //227D41
        return new Color(34, 125, 65);
    }

}
```

The thing is the binding is generally working with a MvxColor-Property, just the conversion seems to be an issue. So probably i just missed something.

So thanks for your help.

Edith: And the property...

```
public bool Changed { get { return m_sValue != m_sSyncValue; } }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strip off the `Mvx`-prefix and the `ValueConverter`-suffix from the converter name in your binding:

Change

```
local:MvxBind="TextColor Changed,Converter=MvxBoolToColorValueConverter" />
```

to

```
local:MvxBind="TextColor Changed,Converter=BoolToColor" />
```

This behaviour is described in the [documentation for ValueConverters](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters):

> This sweep locates all instanciable classes which implement IMvxValueConverter
>   within your assemblies creates an instance of each one registers the
>   instance with the name **stripped of any Mvx prefix and any
>   ValueConverter or Converter postfix**. So, for example, the following
>   class names will all be registered with the same ValueConverter name
>   of "Foo":
>
> Foo, FooValueConverter, FooConverter, MvxFooValueConverter,
>   MvxFooConverter